# Python Flask, custom status of background process as response

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, response

I'm having trouble returning a custom response from a background process that takes a long time and its being called from a view function in Flask. I use the EventSource method from the html to display the status of the process to the user. The process is encapsulated in an object instanced in the view function and I need a way to signalize the status of the process.

The significant parts of the object are:

```
class MyObject:
    self.status = 0
    def signal_status(self):
        yield self.status
    def doSomeProcess(self):
        self.status = 1
        self.foo()
        self.status = 2
        self.bar()
        self.status = 3
    def process_call(self):
        Thread(target=self.async_process, args=(app, data)).start()
    def async_process(self, app, data):
        with app.app_context():
            self.doSomeProcess(data)
```

And from the routes:

```
myObj = MyObject()

@app.route('/process/<data>')
def process(data):
    global myObject
    myObject.process_call(data)
    return render_template('process.html')


@app.route('/progress')
def progress():
    global myObject
    return Response(myObject.signal_status(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

Then I'm trying to reveive the code in js from the response like this:

```
<script>
var source = new EventSource("/progress");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log(event.data);
    }
</script>
```

However nothing appears in the console more than a 200 response message. I've tried casting to str the yield response from signal_status(). If I print the call to signal_status() the number is displayed normaly, so i don't think the threading is the issue.

Am I using the right approach to this issue, or Is there any other way I could display the status of the process in the client?

Comment: Have you considered to use a distributed task queue like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)? My gut feels like you should not implement asynch processing by your own, if something like celery can help you. I personally have collected some good experience with it!